# Tikzpicture chart with custom functions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create the chart drawn below. I have tried using Tikzpicture, but I'm struggling.

```
    \begin{center} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
    \begin{axis}[       
    xlabel=$\kappa''$,      
    ylabel={$x_j^*$}    ]
    xtick={-1,0,...,1},   
    ytick={0.2},    
    \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{center}
```

[image]
Any suggestions as to how I could create this chart?

Comment: and how your functions are defined? if define all coordinates of your function then it is straightforward to draw functions with `addplot coordinates {(..,..) (...,...) ... };`

Comment: There are no values, there are just straight lines. I would like the proportions to be roughly this way.

Comment: and you expect that we will estimate this points from your desultorily sketch for you? what is is actually your problem?

Comment: @pafnuti If my answer is sufficient, please accept it by clicking the green tick ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't use `pgfplots` and my solution is not pretty (It would be cooler with loops and nice tricks, but I've just done it the way I could remember).

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        %Drawing the lines
        \draw [color = red]  (5,0) -- (10, 7.5) -- (15, 7.5);
        \draw [color = blue] (5,0) -- (10, 6.6) -- (15, 6.6);
        \draw [color = red]  (5,0) -- (10, 3.0) -- (15, 3.0);
        \draw [color = blue] (5,0) -- (10, 2.5) -- (15, 2.5);
        \draw (14.9,-.2) -- (15.1,-.1);
        \draw (14.9,-.1) -- (15.1,0);
        %Drawing the border
        \draw [->](0,-5) -- (0,10) -- (15,10) -- (15,-5) -> (0,-5);
        \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (8, -5);
        % Drawing dashed lines
        \draw [dashed,thick] (0,7.5) -- (15,7.5);
        \draw [dashed,thick] (0,6.6) -- (15,6.6);
        % Writing stuff
        \node at (-1,0) {$\frac{n}{s}$};
        \node at (16,7.5) {$\frac{3}{4}$};
        \node at (16,6.6) {$\frac{2}{3}$};
        \node at (16,3.0) {$\frac{1}{3}$};
        \node at (16,2.5) {$\frac{1}{4}$};
        \node at (15,-6) {$\kappa$};
        \node at (8,-6) {B};
        \node at (5,-6) {A};
        \node at (1,-6) {$-\infty$};
        \node at (-1,10) {$x_j$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: Note that it might be useful to change my numbers, if more precise placement is warranted (f.ex. is 3 a rather bad approximation of 10/3)